# how to separate value from table using php array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-4

I would like to separate the value that my `$assets->property_id` displaying... it output 122142 instead of [0] => 122, [1] = 142 and better should be in array format. I wanted to learn how to display this in array so that i can place this to another condition...

```
$user_id = $id;

$type = "TIC";
$asset = ClientPropertyManagement::where('client_id', '=', $user_id)->get();

foreach( $asset as $assets ) {

  if ( $assets->investment_type == $type ) {
    echo $property = $assets->property_id;      
  }

}
```

Im using Laravel 4.2 to display some multiple tables and some conditions to match certain values, etc...

Better Explanation:

I have 2 major tables that i need to connect, **assets table** and **property table**.

In my laravel controller, i need to determine first the user id of the current user once I get the value, I need to pass it under **assets table** to match multiple columns like: “client_id”, “investment_type”, and “property_id”.

Once the “client_id” match the “user id”, i need to check if there was “TIC” type under the “investment_type”, and if there’s a match case, i will need to get the “property_id” and pass it to the **property table** and get “property_mgmt_contact” value and create automated email alert notification.

Answer (score 1):

Use `substr()` to split up the string at the third character.

```
$id = $property = $assets->property_id; 
echo substr($id, 0, 3) . ' ' . substr($id, 3);
```

Comment: Use @Barak's response above, but he omitted the array part (and you didn't specify what *kind* of array you wanted:

$data = array('first_part' => substr($id, 0, 3), 'second_part' => substr($id, 4));

Comment: I don't understand your comment. There's no comment from Barak.

Comment: Maybe your comment should be for the question, not my answer.

Comment: this is working, though i am not sure how to match this as `$properties` as variable inside another condition to match other certain table id...

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. You can assign the concatenated string to a variable, you can put them in an array, you can do anything you want with them. This is very basic programming.

Comment: my bad, sorry, i didn’t clarify the `$properties` came from... 
I put it in this way `$properties = substr($id, 0, 3) . ' ' . substr($id, 4);`, now on each value i would like to match it to another table... my question is, how can i match each value to certain table id again.. btw, i am new and learning laravel.. so please pardon me. :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Laravel. The question you asked didn't really have anything to do with it, you just wanted to know how to put spaces in the output.

Comment: MySQL has its own substring and concatenation functions. You should be able to do a Laravel join with the condition `('some_column', '=', 'concat(substr(property_id, 1, 3), " ", substr(property_id, 4))`

Comment: i see... i put better explanation on my question case.

Answer (score 1):

Your $assets is in object format so to convert it to an array you need this

```
(array) $assets;
```

Your code will look like

```
foreach( $asset as $assets ) {
  $assetsarray =  (array) $assets;
  if ( $assetsarray['investment_type'] == $type ) {
    echo $property = $assetsarray['property_id'].'<br />';      
  }
}
```

If you want to see any array, you can do this

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: it was `Null` when i echo the `var_dump($array);`

Comment: dont use echo there, just var_dump and replace "$array" with your array "$assets".

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that the value from my `$properties` are already in array which is wrong in my first output and use `echo` instead of `print_r`. After initiate to another condition, I need to pass the properties values to another table named `property` and get contact by matching the `property id`.

```
$user_id = $id; // 6 (current logged user)
$asset = ClientPropertyManagement::where('assets.client_id', '=', $user_id)->get();

foreach( $asset as $assets ) {
  if( $assets->investment_type == "TIC"  ) {
    // get property_id under all TIC's column and
    // match the property_id to Property table to get the column of `property_mgmt_contact`.    
    $properties[] = $assets->property_id; 
    // print_r($properties);
  }
}

if( !empty($properties) ){
  $property = DB::table('property')->whereIn('id', $properties)->get();
  foreach( $property as $p ){
    //send email to this email
    $p->property_mgmt_contact;
  }
}
```